# Changing file permissions automatically

Tags: linux, scripting, permissions, directory

At the moment, I paste files to a directory in Linux and it sets the following permissions:

```
rwxr--r--
```

What I'm trying to do is to set the permission to

```
rwxrw-r-- (group write)
```

automatically when I paste a new file into that folder or after a given period, preferably the one more efficient.

There must be an elegant solution to that already, if so can you point me the direction, please?

Comment: Ask [here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) instead.

Comment: I would either migrate or delete  this question to avoid negative votes, but I can't. So please, if you have the power to do so...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These "default rights" are called "umask" in the UNIX world ([see wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Umask)).

I think your problem can be solved by appending a umask command to the /etc/profile script:

```
umask 013
```

Depending on your distributive, there can also be other ways to set umask.